# Higgs to gauge bosons branching ratios

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, higgs, large-hadron-collider

Why does the Higgs to $WW$ branching ratio dominate the $ZZ$ branching ratio so much? Their couplings are quite similar, so what could explain the fact that, at high energies, there are many more $H^0 \to WW$ decays?

Comment: They have different masses and ZZ has the standard factor of $1/2$? I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for here. Can you derive the amplitude?

Comment: Are you asking about the $1/2$ factor in the branching ratio?

Comment: Possibly [useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_coupling).

Answer (score 0):

I think different effects are important: They have different masses ($m_Z > m_W$) and the Higgs to boson couplings $HVV$ are dependend on $m_V$ with $V=W,Z$. Second, the decays into $VV$ includes off-shell bosons since $m_H<2m_V$, which are suppressed depending on the mass of $V$. Further, I am not sure what is meant by "at high energies" since Higgs decays can be discussed in the rest frame of the Higgs boson, though at times before the Higgs discovery, there was of course a Higgs boson mass dependence in the branching fractions.